# What is the difference between these four types of Brahmanas?

Tags: vedas, shatapatha-brahmana, brahmanas, aitareya-brahmana

I got the following four categories of Brahmanas from [*Which of the Brahmana says, "wife is half her husband?"*](https://www.gktoday.in/question/which-of-the-brahamana-sayswife-is-half-her-husban)

> [A] Shatapatha Brahmana
>
> [B] Aitareya Brahmana
>
> [C] Gopatha Brahmana
>
> [D] Taittiriya Brahmana

Any difference between these?

Comment: You mean Brahman or Brahmana- the Brahmin caste?

Comment: Yes Brahmana is what we call the Brahmin or the priestly class. Brahman on the other hand refers to God. So u mean Brahmin here?

Comment: Oh you mean from Brahmana, Aranyakas etc? Oh then it's not about the Brahmins.

Comment: If this is what you are looking for then you'll get the preliminary answer from the shared wiki link.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmana#List_of_Brahmanas ; if you can read devanagari, also visit http://bharatdiscovery.org/india/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A3_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF